# ServiceStack.Redis: No Redis sentinels were available

Tags: sentinel, servicestack.redis

When sentinel excute the method of start(), it will throw an exception that No Redis sentinels were available. 
I've tried both approaches, but neither worked.

- I've tested my sentinels are accessible from the command line.

### **1.Sentinel With Password**

```
_redisManager = new RedisSentinel("123421@47.100.237.179:16379,123421@47.100.237.179:16380".Split(',')).Start();
```

---

> Exception Message:OneTimeSetUp: ServiceStack.Redis.RedisException : No
>   Redis Sentinels were available
>   ---->ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException: UnKnow command 'AUTH'

### **2.Sentinel**

```
_redisManager = new RedisSentinel("47.100.237.179:16379,47.100.237.179:16380".Split(',')).Start();
```

---

> Exception Message:OneTimeSetUp: ServiceStack.Redis.RedisException : No
>   Redis Sentinels were available   ---->
>   ServiceStack.Redis.RedisException : Redis Sentinel is reporting no
>   master is available

---

Comment: Is anyone have this question?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't specify master name:

```
var sentinelHosts = new[]{ "47.100.237.179:16379", "47.100.237.179:16380" };
var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(sentinelHosts, masterName: "mymaster");
IRedisClientsManager redisManager = sentinel.Start();
```